# Java program that gets 10 int number and calculates the average with a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I need to write a java program that gets 10 int numbers and calculates the average.

My requirements are have 3 loops in the same method, while loop, do-while, and for.

For each version, use a loop to input 10 int numbers from the user and calculate the sum. Then display the average.

I would appreciate that help on this. I am having trouble getting the 10 inputs in a loop.

Thanks!

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        // for-loop for 10 integers
        for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 10 integers ");
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at java.util.Scanner class for reading the numbers.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far so we can comment on what you can change to improve it?

Comment: What is the trouble you are having? I am have trouble understanding what the problem is. In fact you can google "java how to I loop 10 times" and get answer for exact 10 times if you can't image how to write such a loop for yourself.

Comment: I need to write a loop that gets 10 integer inputs and calculates the average of the input values. I would post the code I have now but I don't know how. Sorry I'm new to the site and java programming.

Comment: @md05062 To post the code, highlight your code. Copy it. Click in your question. Paste. Then highlight it and press Ctrl+K

Comment: There are tips in the post editor to tell you how to do such things. For code, you indent the first line 4 spaces and then indent each following line a few additional spaces as necessary to keep the tabbed format. Also make sure you have a blank line between any regular text and your code block (both before and after the code)

Comment: I posted it guys. Thanks for the tips. I need to write a loop that gets 10 integer inputs and calculates the average of the input values

Comment: @md05062 check my answer below please I wrote what you exactly need. thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you need to `import java.util.Scanner;`

second create an instance of the class scanner like `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

The loop step:
"The main concept is the same for all the three loops".

You need a loop from 0 to `< 10` or from 1 to `<=10`. Then, you need a variable to store the sum of all the variables entered. Inside the loop you will use the instance you created above to get the 10 numbers such as `sum += input.nextInt()`.

After the loop is finish you divide the sum by 10 and return the outcome.

I hope this is clear.